# How do I construct a local movie URL properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my iPhone app, the user can click a table cell, and a movie will start playing. The movie is a local file in my project under "/Resources/myMovie.m4v".  I can't figure out how to properly link to it though.

I found this code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
NSString *rootPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *filePath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myMovie.m4v"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];

moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO]];
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

is the file definitely in the main bundle?

try using this to get the URL.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myMovie" withExtension:@"m4v"];
   moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the main bundle is.  It's in the project panel in the Resources group.

Comment: MCannon's post should give you what you want. Prior to iOS 4 you'd use `-pathForResource:ofType:`, passing the same arguments, and pass the resulting path to [NSURL fileURLWithPath:]. The main bundle is the .app you're building. On iOS, this is the only type you can create. If the above doesn't work, then I'd suggest making sure that your movie is definitely in the current target— if not, it won't be copied into the app when you build it.

Comment: the main bundle is basically the application bundle, anything that is downloaded with your app from the appstore, is in the main bundle.

Comment: MCannon's answer is correct and should solve your question -> you should accept it using the checkmark.