# How to convert local URL path to a local file path?

Tags: ios, macos, path, nsstring, nsurl

"I have an NSString representing a file URL in form:

```
file://localhost/Users/UserName/Documents/filename.txt
```

what I wish to convert to:

```
/Users/UserName/Documents/filename.txt
```

Is there a method in Cocoa to do this?

If not, is it safe to just delete `file://localhost/` from the start of the string?

---

The simple answer to this seems to be to just delete the "file://localhost" characters at the start of the string. This could be done using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString which creates a new string, or you could use an NSMutableString to hold the string, which is the solution I have at the moment. So the code reads:

```
NSMutableString*     myFileURLString;
NSRange*             myRange;

myFileURLString = [[self getFileURLString] mutableCopy];
myRange.localtion = 0;
myRange.length = [@"file://localhost" length];
[myFileURLString deleteCharcaters:myRange];
```

It's better for me to do it this way, since I want to append and otherwise edit the String once I have it in a standard form.

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372580/how-do-i-construct-a-local-movie-url-properly

Answer (score 3):

Convert the the file URL to an `NSURL` (if you haven't done that already):

```
NSString *urlString = @"file://localhost/Users/UserName/Documents/filename.txt";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

and then simply extract the path component:

```
NSString *path = [url path];
NSLog(@"%@", path);
// Output: /Users/UserName/Documents/filename.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file://localhost/Users/UserName/Documents/filename.txt"];
NSLog(@"path %@",[url path]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Is it a NSString ? If so you can try this
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target 
                                        withString:(NSString *)replacement

Example :

```
myUrlString = [myUrlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://localhost" 
                                        withString:@""];
```

Answer (score -4):

The simple answer to this seems to be to just delete the "file://localhost" characters at the start of the string. This could be done using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString which creates a new string, or you could use an NSMutableString to hold the string, which is the solution I have at the moment. So the code reads:

```
NSMutableString*     myFileURLString;
NSRange*             myRange;

myFileURLString = [[self getFileURLString] mutableCopy];
myRange.localtion = 0;
myRange.length = [@""file://localhost" length];
[myFileURLString deleteCharcaters:myRange];
```

Comment: I can't see what is wrong with the above as it works just fine!